# How to extract email address with the format mail[@]domain.com from html?

Tags: php, html, email, parsing

I want to extract email address from html source.

i was using below to code to extract the email address in the format `mail@domain.com`

```
function extract_email_address ($string) {
    foreach(preg_split('/\s/', $string) as $token) {
        $email = filter_var(filter_var($token, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if ($email !== false) {
            $emails[] = $email;
        }
    }
    return $emails;
}
```

Now, it looks like the email is protected with `[]` symbol, the email address looks like

`mail[@]domain.com`, (Notice the `@` symbol withing `[]`). So, the above code did not help.

anybody knows answer for this question?

Comment: You could just replace `[@]` with `@`.

Comment: nice, it is very simple solution, wondering how i missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just replace [@] with @ - [ Answered by Brad].